# Is there anything like ServerSpec for Azure

Tags: node.js, powershell, azure, azure-storage, azure-mobile-services

I've been bitten by the test-driven infrastructure bug.  My current project is using Azure, including SQL Azure, Azure tables, cloud services, and mobile services.  Configuring an entire environment is somewhat complex.  Now I'm looking for a testing framework that I can use to verify that the environment is configured correctly.  Something like "Confirm that there's a mobile service endpoint named foo, that is has APNS and GCM endpoints, and that there is a Google API key and Apple push certificate associated."  There is more, but that is complex enough that existing tools don't seem to cover it but simple enough to describe in a single sentence.

Because of the number of products, I have to use both the PowerShell module and the cross-platform CLI to script the setup.  The cross-platform CLI looks like the easiest way to get data out (it uses Node and can easily dump JSON data), but I'm at a loss as to how to even start with testing JSON dumps from a Node module that was never really intended to be used as a module.

The PowerShell module is buggy and doesn't have any ability to read mobile services information.

There is a ruby gem for managing Azure, but it's very limited.  So my hope of being able to work all in Ruby was dashed.  There too, I'm not sure how one would use ServerSpec to test a remote node without actually running anything on the remote node.

I'd like to stay within the realm of something that would be understandable by another Azure developer (e.g. JavaScript, PowerShell, and potentially Ruby) and not have to start from scratch with something like Erlang or Brainf**k.

Comment: You may want to look at something like Azure-Scripty which wraps the CLI code to make it easier to consume in scripts.

http://codebetter.com/glennblock/2013/04/01/azure-scripty-azure-cli-scripting-made-even-easier/
https://github.com/azure-contrib/azure-scripty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corey - big area of ongoing build out on Azure right now which is why you are finding limited support.  Resource Manager is aimed at driving programmable infrastructure (http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/xplat-cli-azure-resource-manager/) but doesn't yet encapsulate all Azure service offerings.

There is also the Management Libraries (for .Net) - http://www.bradygaster.com/post/getting-started-with-the-windows-azure-management-libraries or at the most basic of levels there is the pure REST API that you can code directly against if there are bits missing from the above (which is likely) - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460799.aspx

Comment: I think Resource Manager is as close as I'm going to get.